# XPath Next Page navigation

Tags: xpath

I'm using Chrome Data Miner, and so far, failing to extract the data from my query: http://www.allinlondon.co.uk/restaurants.php?type=name&rest=gluten+free

How to code the Next Element Xpath for this website? I tried all the possible web sources, nothing worked.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show some sample HTML that you're trying to extract from, and show what you tried (the XPath), and what the result was.

Comment: Thanks. This is my Google search link: https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gluten+free  . This is my Xpart for each search item  //ol/div/div and this one //div[5]/div/span  is attempting to do the next page jump - rather unsuccessfully!

Comment: It's not clear how either of those XPath expressions relate to your question. Is "next page jump" referring to the same thing as "next element"? And what was the unsuccessful result you encountered?

Comment: Next page, yes. The unsuccessful result refers to the data miner not progressing to collect data from the subsequent pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look for `a` tags (`//a`) whose `descendant::text()` starts with "Next" and then get the `href` attribute of that `a` element.

```
% xpquery -p HTML '//a[starts-with(descendant::text(), "Next")]/@href' 'http://www.allinlondon.co.uk/restaurants.php?type=name&rest=gluten+free'       
 href="http://www.allinlondon.co.uk/restaurants.php?type=name&amp;tube=0&amp;rest=glutenfree&amp;region=0&amp;cuisine=0&amp;start=30&amp;ordering=&amp;expand="
```

Comment: I have no idea where that error came from, perhaps it's internal to Chrome Data Miner?